# Is it possible to garantee the consistency of memoization?

Tags: ocaml, lazy-evaluation, memoization, mutable, side-effects

I want to build a module `I` with memoization. The type `I.t` contains a real complex content `c`, and some mutable properties (eg, `mutable is_cool`). The module provides outside with functions to calculate and get the properties (eg, `is_cool`), which can be costly, that is why mutable properties are used:

```
(*in i.ml *)
module Content = struct
  type t = { i: int; mutable j: int }
  let is_cool (x: t) : bool = ...
end

module I : sig
  type t
  val get_c: t -> Content.t
  val is_cool: t -> bool
  ...
end = struct 
  type t = {
     c : Content.t; 
     mutable is_cool : bool option;
     mutable property_a : int option }

  let get_c (x: t) -> Content.t = x.c

  let is_cool (x: t) : bool = 
    match x.is_cool with
    | Some r -> r
    | None -> (* not yet calculated *)
       let r = Content.is_cool x.c in
       x.is_cool <- Some r;
       r
  end
  ...
```

A concern that I have, is how to code the module `I` and the code outside such that for any value of type `I.t` throughout the program execution, its mutable properties are always consistent with its content `c`. Being consistent means "the mutable properties should either be `None` or be `Some v` where `v` represents the current property of the content".

For instance, the following code tempting to modify directly a property is well forbidden by the signature of the module `I.t`:

```
(* in main.ml *)
open I

let test (x: I.t) = 
  x.is_cool <- Some false
```

However, it seems that it is not easy to forbid this code, which changes the content:

```
(* in main.ml *)
let test (x: I.t) (i_new: int) =
  let c = I.get_c x in
  let c_new = { c with Content.i = i_new } in
  let y = { x with c = c_new } in 
  (* now the content and the properties in y are likely to be inconsistent *)
```

One way to improve this is to add `set` in the module `I`, and always use `set x c_new` at the place of `{ x with c = c_new }`:

```
(*in i.ml *)
let set (x: t) (c: Content.t) : t = 
  { c = c; is_cool = None; property_a = None }
```

However, there are still problems, for instance,

1) it is still impossible to forbid people from writing `{ x with c = c_new }`

2) a modification of the mutable components in `Content.t` (eg, `mutable j: int`) can also make `I.t` inconsistent:

```
(* in main.ml *)
let test (x: I.t) (j_new: int) =
  let c = I.get_c x in
  c.Content.j <- j_new; 
  (* now the content and the properties in x are likely to be inconsistent *)
```

Does anyone know any existing reflexion or solution face to this inconsistency caused by memoization? If we always use `set` at the place of "record with", and do not allow mutable components in `Content.t`, can we guarantee 100% the consistency for any code scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use **private**

Your code would look like this :

```
module type C = sig
  type t = private { i: int; mutable j: int }
  val new_c : int -> int -> t
  val is_cool : t -> bool
end
module Content : C = struct
  type t = { i: int; mutable j: int }
  let new_c = ...
  let is_cool (x: t) : bool = ...
end

module I : sig
  type t
  val new_i : int -> int -> t
  val get_c: t -> Content.t
  val is_cool: t -> bool
  ...
end = struct 
  type t = {
     c : Content.t; 
     mutable is_cool : bool option;
     mutable property_a : int option }

  let new_i = ...

  let get_c (x: t) -> Content.t = x.c

  let is_cool (x: t) : bool = 
    match x.is_cool with
    | Some r -> r
    | None -> (* not yet calculated *)
       let r = Content.is_cool x.c in
       x.is_cool <- Some r;
       r
  end
  ...
```

And if you try to write :

```
 let c = {i = 3; j = 3};;
```

it will reject you answering :

```
 Error: Cannot create values of the private type Content.t
```